# Can you run a cronjob with Amazon SQS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have my app with Elastic Beanstalk and  I need to create a cronjob that run a task in rails

```
rake "sitemap:generate"
```

and I wonder if I can do it with Amazon SQS, anyone knows how to do that?

I tried to do a crontab but it doesn't work in the beanstalk...

```
files:
  "/tmp/cron_job.sh":
    mode: "000777"
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      */2 * * * *  cd /var/app/current/ && RACK_ENV=production bundle exec rake sitemap:generate
    encoding: plain


container_commands:
  01_delete_cron_jobs:
    command: "crontab -r -u ec2-user || exit 0"
  02_add_cron_jobs:
    command: "crontab /tmp/cron_job.sh -u ec2-user"
    leader_only: true
```

Is there another way to do a cronjob in Elastic Beanstalk?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can run a rake task in a crontab in Elastic Beanstalk as follows.

- You may need access to configuration that is set in your profile. If you put the following in a shell script like generate_map.sh, it will include the config that your app is using (this may be overkill for your application). Put this script file in the root of your application.

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  source /etc/profile
  cd /var/app/current
  rake sitemap:generate
  ```
- Put the cronjob you want to run in a text file (like file_with_cron_commands.txt) in your project in the .ebextensions directory. For example, if you want your task to run every minute, that file would include the line below. *Make sure to leave a blank line at the end of your text file.*

  ```
  * * * * * root cd /var/app/current ; sh generate_map.sh
  ```
- In your .config file, use a container command to copy it to the appropriate cron tab directory and set the permissions on it.

  ```
  container_commands:
    01_run_my_gen_map_cron:
      command: "cat .ebextensions/file_with_cron_commands.txt > /etc/cron.d/my_genmap_cron && chmod 644 /etc/cron.d/my_genmap_cron"
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an old question, but it pops up in google search. 
So here is my attempt
You can create a periodic job (like cron jobs)  using SQS with your rails app.

- Create an "worker tier" env which uses SQS for queueing
- in the home folder of your app create a file "cron.yaml"

sample content like

```
#cron.yaml 
version: 1
cron:
 — name: "schedule"
   url: "/schedule"
   schedule: "0 */12 * * *"
```

also checkout:
https://medium.com/@joelennon/running-cron-jobs-on-amazon-web-services-aws-elastic-beanstalk-a41d91d1c571

the gem "active-elastic-job"